# How to work with 'NOT Contains' in cheerio?

Tags: google-apps-script, cheerio

I use the cheeriogs library to work in Google App Script:
Script ID: `1ReeQ6WO8kKNxoaA_O0XEQ589cIrRvEBA9qcWpNqdOP17i47u6N9M5Xh0`
https://github.com/tani/cheeriogs

My current code trying to use not contains looks like this:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Seu Seriado');
  var url = 'https://seuseriado.org/';

  const contentText = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  const $ = Cheerio.load(contentText);
  
    $('h2.entry-title.h6 > a:not(contains("SEM LEGENDA"))')
        .each((index, element) => {sheet.getRange(index+1,1).setValue($(element).text().trim());}); 
}
```

But an error is given:

```
SyntaxError: missing closing parenthesis in :not ("SEM LEGENDA"))
```

What should I do to resolve this issue taking into account that no parentheses are missing and the model for not contains that some cheerio users indicate is exactly the one with equal sign adding parentheses?

Comment: You need the : before contains since it's a pseudo, so I believe it's `a:not(:contains(text))`

Comment: Hello friend @pguardiario , this is exactly the model that has to be used, after some tests and research the solution appeared. I was going to create an answer in 2 days (which is when the stack authorizes me to create it) for anyone who needs it in the future, but as you showed up, could you create the answer for me to mark as a solution? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the : before contains since it's a pseudo, so it's

`a:not(:contains(text))`